# Setting up firebase

Tags: firebase, firebaseui

I want to setup Firebase UI on Android Studio (version 2.1.3). I want to import com.firebase.ui.* but i cant. I have added the following lines to my build.gradle

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.2.0'
```

The last line is where i have a problem. Is there something i am missing? what version of firebase-ui should i use?

Please bare in mind that my gradle sync is successful without the last line

Comment: You're mixing versions. Remove the `firebase-client-android:2.5.2` and update `firebase-ui` to 0.6.0. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782445/how-do-i-setup-firebaseadapter-in-android-studio/39782653#39782653

Comment: i got the same error

Comment: Error:(43, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebaseui:firebaseui:0.6.0
<a href="openFile:C:/My_Android_Studio_Projects/quickstart-android-master/MobileMoneyMarket/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: You have typos in there. Copy/paste `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.6.0'`

Comment: Error:(43, 13) Failed to resolve: com.firebase:firebase-ui:0.6.0
<a href="openFile:C:/My_Android_Studio_Projects/quickstart-android-master/MobileMoneyMarket/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>  Same error has occured

Comment: is there a way i can know the version of firebase-ui installed so that i dont have to try all the versions in my code?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot..i finally figured it out, you were right. i had typos in my code. thanks again

Comment: You can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583379/firebaseui-gives-compilation-error/41006075#41006075

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'
```

Because i think you got the wrong gradle link

Comment: yes i have tried that version and it didnt work, thanks