# FirebaseUI gives compilation error

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0] D:\workspace\demo\SampleLoginDemo\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.firebaseui\firebase-ui\0.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml     Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui" to force usage when used firebaseui.0.4.4

Comment: Well, clearly `minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library`, so are you using SDK 15 as the min?

Answer (score 3):

Change `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'`

to  `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.0'`

In your app/build.gradle dependencies

and

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "....."
        minSdkVersion 14
        ....
    }
```

to

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "....."
        minSdkVersion 16
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much helped with Facebook login error!!

Answer (score 1):

I've just added all of these to `AndroidManifest`:

```
`<uses-sdk
    tools:overrideLibrary="
com.google.example.games.basegameutils,
com.google.firebase.firebase_core,
com.google.firebase.firebase_ads,
com.google.android.gms.play_services,
com.google.android.gms.ads.impl,
com.google.android.gms.ads,
com.google.android.gms.analytics,
com.google.android.gms.appinvite,
com.google.android.gms.auth.api,
com.google.android.gms.auth,
com.google.android.gms.cast.framework,
com.google.android.gms.cast,
com.google.android.gms.clearcut,
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig,
com.google.android.gms.contextmanager,
com.google.firebase.crash,
com.google.firebase.auth.api,
com.google.firebase.database,
com.google.firebase.database.connection,
com.google.firebase.messaging,
com.google.firebase.storage,
com.google.android.gms.all,
com.google.android.gms.ads,
com.google.android.gms.auth,
com.google.android.gms.base,
com.google.android.gms.measurement,
com.google.android.gms,
com.google.android.gms.analytics,
com.google.android.gms.appindexing,
com.google.android.gms.appinvite,
com.google.android.gms.appstate,
com.google.android.gms.cast,
com.google.android.gms.drive,
com.google.android.gms.fitness,
com.google.android.gms.location,
com.google.android.gms.maps,
com.google.android.gms.games,
com.google.android.gms.gcm,
com.google.android.gms.identity,
com.google.android.gms.nearby,
com.google.android.gms.panorama,
com.google.android.gms.plus,
com.google.android.gms.safetynet,
com.google.android.gms.wallet,
com.google.android.gms.gass,
com.google.android.gms.iid,
com.google.android.gms.instantapps,
com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.impl,
com.google.android.gms.tagmanager,
com.google.android.gms.measurement.impl,
com.google.firebase.iid,
com.google.firebase,
com.google.android.gms.vision,
com.google.android.gms.wearable,
com.google.android.gms.tasks"/>'
```

Took ages! :)

Answer (score 0):

minSdkVersion is 16 in library `[com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0]`

So you can't set minSdkVersion less than that in your app.