# client query of firebase database not accepting at constructor

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

i am creating FirebaseListAdapter for data at firebase database, At the constructor 4th parameter of FirebaseListAdapter i passed a com.firebase.client.Query but it's not accepting method not resolve error thrown.
here is code for FirebaseListAdapter i used

```
package com.example.zar.shoppingfirebase.ui.activeLists;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.zar.shoppingfirebase.R;
import com.example.zar.shoppingfirebase.model.ShoppingList;
import com.firebase.client.Query;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;



 /**
  * Created by Zar on 1/25/2017.
  */

public class ActiveListAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<ShoppingList> {

public ActiveListAdapter(Activity activity, Class<ShoppingList> modelClass,    int modelLayout,Query ref)
{
    super(activity,modelClass,modelLayout,ref);
    this.mActivity=activity;
}

@Override
protected void populateView(View v, ShoppingList model, int position) {
    TextView textViewListName= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_list_name);
    TextView textViewCreatedByUser= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_created_by_user);

    textViewListName.setText(model.getListName());
    textViewCreatedByUser.setText(model.getOwner());
}
```

**ScreenShots**
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCNn1.png)

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.zar.shoppingfirebase"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

/* Firebase SDK*/
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'

/* Firebase UI */
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'

/* For Google Play Services*/
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You're trying to use the old 2.x version of the Firebase SDK for Android (i.e. `com.firebase.client.Query`), but likely are using the latest version of FirebaseUI. Make sure that all Firebase dependencies in your gradle file are for Firebase version 9.x or higher.

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782445/how-do-i-setup-firebaseadapter-in-android-studio/39782653#39782653

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

    /* Firebase SDK*/
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.1'

    /* Firebase UI */
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'

    /* For Google Play Services*/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'

Comment: i changed these but still there is the same problem with constructor.

Comment: Share the minimal code and gradle file that still reproduces the problem please. Do so by editing your question. Having multiple lines of code in a comment is unreadable.

Comment: i added build.gradle (Modul:app).

Comment: You still include `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'`. Remove that, then make the code work again

Comment: you can see it in screenshot section of question.

Comment: You'll need to import the Firebase classes from the new SDK. There's a great migration guide for that on https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Comment: the libraries which i included in gradle build giving me a class of FirebaseListAdapter and the constructor of that class able to accept only database.Query instead of client.Query i want to pass client.Query.

Comment: I wrote those classes. They accept both `Query` and a `DatabaseReference`. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/0.4.0/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseListAdapter.java#L66. If it doesn't accept your query, you're likely still passing `com.firebase.client.Query` (from SDK version 2.x) instead of `com.google.firebase.database.Query` (from SDK version 9 or higher).

Comment: i want to pass com.firebase.client.Query any solution for this?

Comment: You can't use Firebase SDK 2.x with FirebaseUI 0.4. They're not compatbie. Throw away the dependency on `'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'` and follow the migration guide.

Comment: thanks for your help. highly appriciatable